# asctime() weird behaviour

Tags: c, time.h

I have the following code.

```
 #include<time.h>
 #include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
  time_t t1, t2;
  time(&t1);/* set current time to t1 */

  struct tm T1, T2;
  int i;       
  scanf("%d", &i); /* for delaying */
  time(&t2); /* set current time to t2 */

  T1 = *(struct tm*)localtime(&t1);
  T2 = *(struct tm*)localtime(&t2);

  printf("%s%s", asctime(&T1), asctime(&T2)); /* display them */
}
```

Basically, i want to get the current time on t1 and then(after a delay caused by waiting for i to be read) the current time on t2. t1 and t2 are different and so are T1.tm_sec and T2.tm_sec, but the printf displays the exact same date(the one corresponding to T1). I know that internally, asctime(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/asctime/?kw=asctime) uses an static pointer, but i tried a smaller sample program with a function returning a static char pointer and they worked.

```
char* test(int t) {
    static char result[10];
    sprintf(result, "%d", t);

    return result;
}
```

and the i use it like this

```
printf("%s ", test(5));
printf("%s ", test(7));
```

and it works(the string printed is different).

So i guess it can't be from there. I also copied the asctime code(from cplusplus) and put some printfs inside the function and i noticed that result variable gets correctly update after the sprintf statement.

So what happens that printf displays the same date?

The asctime code from cplusplus.com

```
char* asctime(const struct tm *timeptr)
{
   static const char wday_name[][4] = {
    "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
   };
  static const char mon_name[][4] = {
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
};
  static char result[26];
  sprintf(result, "%.3s %.3s%3d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %d\n",
    wday_name[timeptr->tm_wday],
    mon_name[timeptr->tm_mon],
    timeptr->tm_mday, timeptr->tm_hour,
    timeptr->tm_min, timeptr->tm_sec,
    1900 + timeptr->tm_year);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your "test" isn't valid, since you're not doing `printf("%s and %s\n", test(5), test(7));`, i.e. not expecting the same single buffer to contain two different values at the same time.

Comment: `printf("%s",asctime()); printf("%s",asctime());` is quite different from `printf("%s %s",asctime(),asctime());`: in the second case, you call `asctime` twice before printing, hence the second call overwrites the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in:

```
printf("%s%s", asctime(&T1), asctime(&T2));
```

and

```
printf("%s ", test(5));
printf("%s ", test(7));
```

The first one (which also causes what you define as "weird" behavior) uses a static memory location to store the string. The second call overwrites the result of the first call.

In your second example, you actually use the result of the first call, then call the function a second time. In order to save the both results, you could do the following:

```
printf("%s%s", strdup(asctime(&T1)), strdup(asctime(&T2)));
```

Which would allocate a copy and store the result there. Still better is something like this:

```
char *result1 = strdup(asctime(&T1)), *result2 = strdup(asctime(&T2));

printf("%s%s", result1, result2);

free(result1);
free(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your test with `test` function checked other scenario than the one with `asctime`. With `test`:

```
printf("%s ", test(5));
printf("%s ", test(7));
```

you have two separate function calls, while with `asctime` you have

```
printf("%s%s", asctime(&T1), asctime(&T2)); /* display them */
```

two calls as arguments in one function. Arguments are evaluated before calling the `printf` function, so the wrong behaviour of `asctime` is visible - one of the calls to `asctime` overwrites the result of the other one. Copy the result of `asctime` somewhere before calling it again ot better use `asctime_r`.